# How to set context variable from database

Tags: talend

I'm trying to set a context variable from a row in a oracle database. I have the table in the database already set up like so:

```
key     | variable
name    | BigDecimal
```

I also have created a BigDecimal context variable. How do I link the context variable to the database so it can be used in a SQL query?

Comment: you will have to have in your database table key, value columns or similar..then you have to use tContextLoad component in talend to set the context variables in your job. you would also have to have these contexts goups/variables defined in your job or in your repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a table with schema `(variable_name, variable_value)` and each row id dedicated to a single job, then I recommand you to add a third column so it will be `(variable_name, variable_value, job_name)`, then with simple single query you will get the row of the current job:

```
select variable_name, variable_value from context_table where job_name = '"+jobName+"';
--jobName is varibale global exists in each Talend by defaults
```

[image]

If your table is not modeled to serve context, but you need a specefic value from that table to be loaded into context, you have to execute the query using TOracleRow and pass the result to tJavaRow that have the code below:

```
context.myVariable = input_row.myColumn
```

If you want to use that context variable in other queries, your query will be like this:

```
"select a, b, c from table1 where a = '"+context.myVariable+"'"
```

Comment: Is there something specific I need to do to create a key-value schema in the table? Currently the database has the columns name and a value column. I need the same row every time for this job (each row in the table is for a separate job and is updated regularly). Does this change how I should implement this in any way?