# Setting a context variable from a count sql statement

Tags: sql, integration, talend, data-management

I am new to Talend and appreciate any help. I have a mysql input (tMSSqlInput) with the statement: `select count(*) as row_count
from app.ImportFile a where 1;`

What I would like to do: Do Select count statement in database and assign to variable.

Does this look right for setting the context variable:

tMSSqlInput ----> if statement(don't know what to include here)---->tSetGlobalVar

I have read: [Setting a database value to context variable in talend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468536/setting-a-database-value-to-context-variable-in-talend) and
[How to set context variable from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31384867/how-to-set-context-variable-from-database) but they are about SQL statements that have a select statement with column names.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `tJavaRow`, I prefer to use `tSetGlobalVar` instead. This makes it more clear as to exactly what you are trying to do: set a global variable using the input from the tMSSQLInput.

```
tMSSQLInput---main--->tSetGlobalVar
```

In the first column of `tSetGlobalVar`, add the name of the global map variable you want, for example "rowCount"

In the second column of `tSetGlobalVar`, you put in rown.count, where "rown" is the name of the row coming from tMSSQLInput, and "count" is the name of the field specified in your tMSQLInput schema.

Answer (score 0):

```
what you can do is below
tMSSqlInput-->tJavaRow (here you can populate your global variable...lets say your schema column name was row_count then here you can put logic as 
globalMap.put("row_count_received",input_row.row_count);
and then you can use if conditional subjob trigger

tMSSQLInput--->tJavaRow
|
|if condition ---  (((Integer)globalMap.get("row_count_receive"))==1
V
do your operation

similarly you can fork another if statement and where count=0 like above..
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, added: globalMap.put("row_count_received",row3.row_count);
System.out.println("test: "+row3.row_count); but print out was -> test: null

Comment: what is row3...can you show post image of your job..also use input_row.row_count in tJavaRow...input_row is what you can use inside tJavarow, irrespective of whatever is teh incoming connection name.